Tzoraas on clothing: the Torah describing which types of clothing?
In the section on negaim on clothing, the first posuk describes various types that get negaim:
וְהַבֶּ֕גֶד כִּֽי־יִהְיֶ֥ה ב֖וֹ נֶ֣גַע צָרָ֑עַת בְּבֶ֣גֶד צֶ֔מֶר א֖וֹ בְּבֶ֥גֶד פִּשְׁתִּֽים׃ א֤וֹ בִֽשְׁתִי֙ א֣וֹ בְעֵ֔רֶב לַפִּשְׁתִּ֖ים וְלַצָּ֑מֶר א֣וֹ בְע֔וֹר א֖וֹ בְּכׇל־מְלֶ֥אכֶת עֽוֹר׃
Got that? Wool or linen, warp or weft, plus anything from leather.
In case you forgot, the next verse says
וְהָיָ֨ה הַנֶּ֜גַע יְרַקְרַ֣ק ׀ א֣וֹ אֲדַמְדָּ֗ם בַּבֶּ֩גֶד֩ א֨וֹ בָע֜וֹר אֽוֹ־בַשְּׁתִ֤י אוֹ־בָעֵ֙רֶב֙ א֣וֹ בְכׇל־כְּלִי־ע֔וֹר
Then two verses later
וְרָאָ֨ה אֶת־הַנֶּ֜גַע בַּיּ֣וֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִ֗י כִּֽי־פָשָׂ֤ה הַנֶּ֙גַע֙ בַּ֠בֶּ֠גֶד אֽוֹ־בַשְּׁתִ֤י אֽוֹ־בָעֵ֙רֶב֙ א֣וֹ בָע֔וֹר לְכֹ֛ל אֲשֶׁר־יֵעָשֶׂ֥ה הָע֖וֹר לִמְלָאכָ֑ה
This happens nine times, including the very last verse
זֹ֠את תּוֹרַ֨ת נֶֽגַע־צָרַ֜עַת בֶּ֥גֶד הַצֶּ֣מֶר ׀ א֣וֹ הַפִּשְׁתִּ֗ים א֤וֹ הַשְּׁתִי֙ א֣וֹ הָעֵ֔רֶב א֖וֹ כׇּל־כְּלִי־ע֑וֹר לְטַהֲר֖וֹ א֥וֹ לְטַמְּאֽוֹ׃
Why is it repeated so often?
Suggestion: It could be that the reason is that the Torah just does not have a single word for this combination. In support of that, it twice just says something like this:
אֵ֥ת אֲשֶׁר־בּ֖וֹ הַנָּ֑גַע
"whatever has the nega in it"
It still bothers me; I imagine that Hashem "looked into the Torah and created the world", using lashon hakodesh. I generally expect לשה"ק to be better suited to the task. Are there other examples like this?

Ramban at the end of his comment to Vayikra 13:47 addresses this question, but I’m not clear on what he is saying.

Ramban there: "ועל דרך הפשט מפני זה יחזירו הכתוב בכל פסוק ופסוק הבגד או העור או השתי והערב כי הדבר נס ולרבותינו בהם מדרשים וכולם בתורת כהנים". "the reason why it repeats in every verse the expression 'the garment, or the skin, or the wrap and the woof,' is because the matter is miraculous. Our Rabbis have interpretations for these repetitions, and all of them are found in the Torath Kohanim."

This is a good question the Haemek Davar (Netziv) deals with.
Sorry for any poor translations:
Haemek Davar 13:49- ובאמת כל הפרטים מיותר בזה המקרא שהרי כבר פי׳ הכתוב במקרא הקודם. אלא בא ללמד שאינו דומה פרטים של צרעת לפרטים של טומאת מגע דבטומאת מגע העץ המשמש את המתכות והוא יד לכלי מתכות ה״ה ככלי מתכות ולא כן בצרעת דאפילו מחובר לבגד או להעור איזה מין אחר אין חל עליו דיני צרעת וכדתנן במשנה דנגעים ובת״כ. והיינו שדייק הכתוב שיהא המראה דוקא בבגד וגו׳ והכי תניא בת״כ בבגד ולא בנימין כו׳. ומעתה נקיט הכתוב הפשוט תחלה כדרך הכתובים. והחל בבגד או בעור. שאין הטפל להם הכרחי כ״כ וגם בלי הטפל יהיו בגד ועור משא״כ שו״ע אין להם שם שו״ע בלי כלי הארג. והם מוכרחים לזה השם קמ״ל דמכ״מ אין העץ של הארג מק״ט. ועדיין הייתי אומר דוקא עץ הארג דאינו מצורף לשו״ע לעולם רק עד שתהא נגמרת האריגה אבל מלאכת עור יוכל להיות שאיזה חתיכת עץ וכדומה מחובר לעור מה שא״א להיות הכלי בלעדו קמ״ל דמכ״מ דוקא בעור שבו חל הצרעת ולא במחובר לעור. He basically asks your question, and then says, there are differences between the impurity caused by contact with certain materials, like metals, and the impurity caused by tzara'at. While the impurity from contact with metals extends to the material itself, tzara'at does not necessarily affect the garment or skin it's attached to as mentioned in the Mishneh in Negaim and Torat Kohanim. The passuk then says the המראה is specifically by the garments. He then continues to explain the other items.
13:51- כאן שינה הכתוב בעור. וגם כאן עיקר ביאור הפרטים מיותר אלא ללמדנו דהפשיון ג״כ אינו אלא בגוף הבגד ולא בטפל לבגד ממין אחר. והנה כנגד זה יש חומר בצרעת משארי טומאת מגע דאם נחתך מטלית מזה הבגד המוסגר או העור וטלה על מקום אחר ואח״כ נמצא באותו מטלית נגע נחשב לפשיון ומועיל לטמא את גוף הבגד או העור שנחתך ממנו בעת שהיה מוסגר כדתנן בנגעים פ״י. מעתה אם לקח חתיכת עור לשמש לכלי עץ או מתכות אע״ג שאם היה מתחלה כך לא היה מק״ט כלל שהרי לא מיקרי כלי עור. דעיקר הכלי הוא עץ ומתכות. אלא השתא שכבר העור הוא בהסגר ואח״כ נמצא פשיון ע״ז החתיכה שמשמש את העץ ומתכות מועיל שיהא נחשב לפשיון לגוף העור שנחתך ממנו. והיינו דמדייק הכתוב או בעור לכל אשר יעשה העור למלאכה. היינו שנטפל העור למלאכת כלי עץ או מתכות. מכ״מ יש בו דין פשיון. All the details here come again to teach us that the manifestation of impurity (פשיון) is indeed only on the body of the garment and not on something attached to it of a different kind. However, regarding this, there is a distinction with tzara'at from the remnants of impurity by contact. If a piece is cut from this garment or skin and placed elsewhere, and then it is found that the same piece has tzara'at, it is considered impure for imparting impurity to the body of the garment or skin from which it was cut when it was attached, as stated in the Mishnah regarding negaim. Now, if one were to take a piece of leather to serve as part of a wooden or metal vessel, even though initially it wouldn't be called a vessel at all because it's not primarily made of leather, as the main material for the vessel is wood and metal. However, now that the leather is already incorporated and then it is found to have tzara'at due to the attachment serving the wood and metal, it is effective in imparting impurity to the body of the skin from which it was cut. This is why the scripture specifies "or skin for whatever work skin is used for," meaning that the skin is attached for the work of making vessels of wood or metal. Therefore, it has the status of impurity.
13:52- חזר ופירש כל הפרטים ללמדנו שגם השריפה אינה בטפל להם. It's reiterated and explained to teach us that even burning is not considered an attachment to them.
13:53- חזר המקרא על כל הפרטים להשמענו דכאן יש כיבוס אפילו בכלי עור. וכבר הוי בזה טובא בזבחים פ׳ דם חטאת. The Chumash reiterated all the details to emphasize that here there is laundering even with leather vessels. This is already extensively discussed in Zevachim.
13:58- חזר המקרא עוד על כל הפרטים ללמדנו דאפי׳ השתי וערב או איזה כלי עור שאינם מקבלים טומאה זולת צרעת. בעי טבילה הנהוג בכל טומאת מגע ג״כ. ולא הוי כמפץ שמקבל טומאת מדרס ואין לה טהרה במקוה משום שאינן כלי כדאי׳ שבת דפ״ד א. The Chumash repeated all the details again to teach us that even vessels such as a sheti or a leather vessel that do not accept impurity except tzara'at require immersion, which is customary for all impurities by contact as well. And it is not like a threshold that becomes impure but cannot be purified in a mikveh because they are not vessels, as discussed in Masechet Shabbat.
(Just to point out: He does not give an answer for the repetition for Pesukim 56, 57, 59)
For 13:59 the Malbim says, כל מיני בגדים בפרטות להרות שכולם נכנסים תחת סוג בגד וכולם נכללים במ"ש שם "לצרעת הבגד ולבית" (דס"ל לת"ק דבר הלמד בהיקש אן חוזר ומלמד בהיקש וע"כ מפרש שזה אינו היקש לבגד רק גלה שהם בכלל בגד וכולם מוקשים לבית. ורבי סבר שדבר הלמד בהיקש חוזר ומלמד בהיקש לכן עשה מזה שני היקשים – בגד לבית, וכולם לבגד. וכבר בארנו בפ' צו (סימן כג) שכל מקום שאומר מלת "זאת" בא למעט – רק זאת, לא דבר אחר. ולת"ק ממעט שאין צריך צפרים כבית, ולרבי שההיקש דפה הוא לבגד, ממעט שאין שתי וערב מטמא רק בנגעים, לא ביתר טומאות. The pasuk mentions the clothes in details to teach that all of them are considered under the term בגד which are all under לצרעת הבגד ולבית, and then continues to explain why this is.

Wow. Thank you.
